# Probability of an invalid "minefield" in riichi mahjong

Tags: probability

In "minefield mahjong", your goal is to make the highest scoring valid hand out of a group of tiles. I am wondering the possibility of there being no valid hands in the set of tiles.

The makeup of a set:

- 3 suits, each containing 4 copies of the numbers 1-9
- 7 honors, with 4 copies of each

for a total of 136 tiles.

In a minefield, you have 34 tiles. A minefield that cannot create a valid hand includes the following:

- 1 of each honor
- 6 unique tiles from each suit, of which no 3 make a same-suit run (9 valid possibilities per suit*)
- and then either:

  - 3 more copies each of 3 different tiles already drawn (making 3 four of a kinds and 22 unique tiles), or,
  - 3 copies each of 2 different tiles already drawn and 1 additional copy of 3 different tiles already drawn (making 2 four of a kinds, 3 pairs and 20 unique tiles)

The math I tried never seems to be working out. I know the total number of minefields is $\binom{136}{34}$, but I'm not sure how to calculate the number that fulfill the criteria.

*$[124578, 124589, 124579, 124689, 125689, 134679, 134689, 135689, 235689]$ are the valid combinations in a suit

Comment: Not sure I follow this.  If I understand it correctly, we cannot choose all the first $4$ distribution of the non-honor cards, as this would give $3$ four-of-a-kinds: $1,2,$ and $4$ and $1$ three-of-a-kind: $8$, a possibility not listed as valid.  Is this right?

Comment: There will be only one of the distributions for each of the non-honor suits. The goal for the non-honor ones is to have no same-suit runs of 3 (eg. 1 2 3); A valid example minefield would be - Suit 1: 111124578, Suit 2: 134679, Suit 3: 235689, Honors: 1234566667777

Comment: Oh wait, I think I understand.  When you say "four-of-a-kind" you mean four of the same suit and rank.  I was thinking it just meant four of the same rank.

Comment: Yeah sorry for the confusion. Four of the exact same tile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $9$ choices for the non-honor cards in each suit, so we have $9^3=729$ ways to choose which tile values will occur in the hand.  In any event there will be $25$ distinct tile vaules.  In the first case, there are $\binom{25}{3}$ ways to choose which tiles will be four-of-a-kinds, and $4^{22}$ ways to choose the tiles that occur only once.  Of course there's only one way to choose which tiles make up a four-of-a-kind.  Therefore, case $1$ gives $$9^3\cdot4^{22}\binom{25}{3}$$ possibilities.

In the second case, we have $\binom{25}{2}$ ways to choose the ranks of the four-of-a-kinds, and then $\binom{23}{3}$ ways to choose the ranks of the pairs.  For the pairs, we have $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways to choose which tiles make up the pair.  This gives $$9^3\cdot3^6\cdot4^{20}\binom{25}{2}\binom{23}{3}$$ possibilities for case $2$.

I computed the probability to be $$2.408361017451432\cdot10^{-9}$$

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer as it answered the question I asked with the criteria I gave. However, for archival purposes if someone searches for this question: when generating the criteria for the question I forgot about the "13 orphans" hand. Factoring that in gives the actual probability of an invalid "minefield" at $3.275004517234960\cdot10^{-10}$